# Span regex replacement

Tags: php, regex, youtube, preg-replace

I have a text in my databse. For example:

```
Dummy Text Here...
<span class="youtube">nmkW544sK9U</span>

Dummy Text Here...
<span class="youtube">yUBKZvq5G2g</span>
```

...and I need it to be replaced with:

```
Dummy Text Here...
<iframe width="640" height="395" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nmkW544sK9U?rel=0"></iframe>

Dummy Text Here...
<iframe width="640" height="395" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yUBKZvq5G2g?rel=0"></iframe>
```

But I don't know regular expressions well enough and ask you to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work.

```
$replacement = '<iframe width="640" height="395" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0"></iframe>';
preg_replace('/<span class="youtube">(\w+)<\/span>/', $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, don't use regex to parse HTML. It will cause you pain.

The nicest way to do this is with a genuine DOM parser. PHP's `DOMDocument` is ideal.

For instance:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//span[@class="youtube"]');

while ($node = $nodes->item(0)) {
    $iframe = $dom->createElement('iframe');
    $iframe->setAttribute('width', 640);
    $iframe->setAttribute('height', 395);
    $iframe->setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
    $iframe->setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
    $iframe->setAttribute('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $node->nodeValue . '?rel=0');

    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($iframe, $node);
}

$yourHTML = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why regex is such a pain? For more complicated operations I agree with you, but for such a simple replacement I can't see any problem?

Comment: @Arend It's probably fine. Until the source changes. Or it gets slightly more complicated. If the pattern is *absolutely* certain, it would probably be all right -- but if it changes even slightly, you're stuffed.

Comment: @Arend regexes can not handle easily nesting of tags. That's the issue unless you are sure of the static tag nesting.

Comment: @millebii, sure, sure. But this is not a clear example of where you need high end support for nesting. Let it be clear, I agree with you. But I'm asking these questions because I find remarks like "It will cause you pain" quite unhelpful.

Comment: @Arend It was meant humourously, but it contains truth. Parsing HTML with regex will generally not solve your problem in an attractive and stable way, because it's so inflexible.

Comment: @lonesomeday, Sure, but there are also some advantages, in this case it's a relatively inexpensive operation for a useful simple templateing case instead of a quite expensive DOM operation in php. In terms of flexibility: changing a regex pattern is hardly rocket science.

Comment: @Arend Except where you have to add complexity -- then it becomes very complicated. For instance, perhaps you have to exclude `<span class="youtube">` if it occurs within `pre` tags. Or within comments. Or if the span could have other attributes.

Comment: @lonesomeday, I suppose it's a matter of preference and your knowledge of regex.